# Custom Exception class doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, exception, global-asax

Why classes that inerithes from `System.Exception` don't work in try catch block?

The following snipped doesn't fire catch block

```
try
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 0;
    int c = a/b;
}
catch (CustomEx er)
{    
  Console.Write(er.Message);
}

public class  CustomEx:Exception
{

}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't work" ? It does not compile ? var ex = (CustomEx)Server.GetLastError(); should compile. But I wouldn't try casting explicitly, as there can be many error causes. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: i've changed a bit the question because the problem is with every error not only with getlasterror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided cannot work because the division throws a `DivideByZeroException` and you're catching `CustomEx` which inherits from `Exception` but definitely not from `DivideByZeroException`.